# Changing Utc time to localtime

Tags: c#, datetime

How can i change the UTC time to local time.

I have this code,

```
DateTime dt = booking.CreateDateTime.Value;
```

where CreationDateTime is in the form of UTC.

When ever i change the time to local time on client side, it is 7 hours faster then the local time.

Any body has Idea on this.

This is how i am changing it to local time.

```
var localTime = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(dt);
```

When booking is made, sever side code for datetime is

```
booking.CreateDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Comment: Is the Current Time Zone on that machine in fact the current time zone for where you are?

Comment: Yup this code is from mobile application which is in Australia/Canberra

Comment: Check the Kind property of "dt". Maybe the it is not UTC as you expect: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind.aspx

Comment: How do you know the date is UTC?

Comment: @AmritSharma if you want to convert `dt`(utc time) to localtime. And you told utc is 7 hours faster then what about `DateTime localTime = dt.AddHours(7);`

Answer (score 0):

There are really only two things that could be wrong:

1. The UTC date is not really UTC.
2. The machine on which this is running is not set to the right time zone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like .net is assuming the date is in local time. In the following code, dt1 and dt3 are both the same as dt. One solution would be to to use TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset and do the calculation yourself.

```
dt = Now
dt1 = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(dt)
dt2 = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToUniversalTime(dt)
dt3 = dt.ToLocalTime
dt4 = dt.ToUniversalTime
```